# Recursion Puzzle

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Recently, one of my friends challenged me to solve this puzzle which goes as follows:

Suppose that you have two variables x and y. These are the only variables which can be used for storage in the program. There are three operations which can be done:

- Operation 1: x = x+y
- Operation 2: x = x-y
- Operation 3: y = x-y

Now, you are given two number n1 and n2 and a target number k. Starting with x = n1 and y = n2, is there a way to arrive at x = k using the operations mentioned above? If yes, what is the sequence of operations which can generate x = k.

Example: If n1 = 16, n2 = 6 and k = 28 then the answer is YES. The sequence is:

```
Operation 1
Operation 1
```

If n1 = 19, n2 = 7 and k = 22 then the answer is YES. The sequence is:

```
Operation 2
Operation 3
Operation 1
Operation 1
```

Now, I have wrapped my head around the problem for too long but I am not getting any initial thoughts. I have a feeling that this is recursion but I do not know what should be the boundary conditions. It would be very helpful if someone can direct me towards an approach which can be used to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use more variables/data structures in order to find this sequence of ops?

Comment: Yes. That is allowed.

Comment: Finding shortest sequence if one exists can be done with BFS. Not sure yet what stop clause will make sure to determine there is no possible sequence.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a litte as to how can BFS be used?

Comment: It seems to me that the last two rules yield the greatest common divisor (GCD) of your inputs (or a multiple of that). The first rule can then be used to get any multiple of the GCD. So if the target is a multiple of the GCD it's possible, otherwise it's not.

Comment: That is a very interesting observation @Heuster.

Comment: @Heuster I noticed it too, but I got stuck trying to prove it. Do you have any leads on that?

Comment: @amit I tried to give a proof, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not a complete answer, but a proof that a sequence exists if and only if `k` is a multiple of the greatest common divisor (GCD) of `n1` and `n2`. Let's write `G = GCD(n1, n2)` for brevity.

First I'll prove that `x` and `y` are always integer multiples of the `G`. This proof is really straightforward by induction. Hypothesis: `x = p * G` and `y = q * G`, for some integers `p` and `q`.

- Initially, the hypothesis holds by definition of `G`.
- Each of the rules respects the induction hypothesis. The rules yield:

  1. `x + y = p * G + q * G = (p + q) * G`
  2. `x - y = p * G - q * G = (p - q) * G`
  3. `y - x = q * G - p * G = (q - p) * G`

Due to this result, there can only be a sequence to `k` if `k` is an integer multiple of the GCD of `n1` and `n2`.

For the other direction we need to show that *any* integer multiple of `G` can be achieved by the rules. This is definitely the case if we can reach `x = G` and `y = G`. For this we use [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations). Consider the second implementation in the linked wiki article:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    while a ≠ b
        if a > b
           a := a − b
        else
           b := b − a
    return a
```

This is a repetitive application of rules 2 and 3 and results in `x = G` and `y = G`.

---

Knowing that a solution exists, you can apply a BFS, as shown in [Amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22503793/2095090), to find the shortest sequence.

Comment: @angainor The starting values for `x` and `y` are `n1` and `n2`, respectively. Obviously, `n1` is a multiple of `GCD(n1, n2)`, because it is the greatest **common divisor**. Similar for `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a solution exists, finding the shortest sequence to get to it can be done using a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

The pseudo code should be something like:

```
queue <- new empty queue
parent <- new map of type map:pair->pair
parent[(x,y)] = 'root' //special indicator to stop the search there
queue.enqueue(pair(x,y))
while !queue.empty():
   curr <- queue.dequeue()
   x <- curr.first
   y <- curr.second
   if x == target or y == target:
      printSolAccordingToMap(parent,(x,y))
      return
   x1 <- x+y
   x2 <- x-y
   y1 <- x-y
   if (x1,y) is not a key in parent:    
      parent[(x1,y)] = (x,y)
      queue.enqueue(pair(x1,y))
   //similarly to (x2,y) and (x,y1)
```

The function `printSolAccordingToMap()` simply traces back on the map until it finds the root, and prints it.

Note that this solution only finds the optimal sequence if one exists, but will cause infinite loop if one does not exist, so this is only partial answer yet.

Comment: This just finds a solution, not necessarily the most optimal one.

Comment: @Skizz From optimality of bfs, the solution found by this algorithm is the shortest possible one.

Comment: Also, it shouldn't terminate on y==target.

Comment: Try it with x=3,y=1,k=2! Using the algorithm presented, the queue at the start of each iteration is: [3,1]-> [4,1|2,1|3,2]-> [4,1|2,1|5,2|1,2]-> skip 1,2-> [4,1|2,1|7,2|5,3](3,2 not pushed)-> [4,1|2,1|7,2|8,3|2,3]->done in 4 steps (optimal is 1) EDIT: isn't this more of a depth first solution? A breadth first would need two lists surely - the values at the current depth and the values at the next level down?

Comment: @Skizz Depth first will be the same - but using a stack instead of a queue. You are right about y==target should be canceled if looking only for reaching with x. Your example is using a stack rather than a queue, which is used in the pseudo code and in BFS. The code will generate the queue as follows: [3,1|2,1|3,2]->[5,2|1,2|4,1|2,1]->done, because x=2 is in the head now.

Comment: You can find sub-optimal scenarios for both fifo and filo approaches.

Comment: @Skizz No,you cannot. BFS is FIFO approach,and it is proven to be optimal - it finds shortest path from source to all nodes. In here, you basically have a graph. Each vertex is a pair (x,y). Each edge is one of the possible operations you can do (branch factor=3). We reduced it to shortest path problem on the described graph, and we are looking for the shortest path from the initial (x,y) to any node with `x=target`. BFS is complete (if there is a solution it will find one) and optimal (finds the shortest path). Since the path lengths is the number of ops we did, the solution found is optimal.

Comment: @Skizz If you are still unsure why this pseudo code is basically a BFS very similar to the [pseudo code in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode) I will be happy to show you on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50051/discussion-between-amit-and-skizz) step by step.

Comment: @amit But I think, this would not be the best algorithm, because suppose the height of recursion tree reaches to 500, means, `3^500` nodes. For this type of situation, your algo will proove to be poor, in terms of time complexity.

Comment: @devnull Never claimed it to be quick, just correct. I didn't want to post it as an answer initially, only did because OP asked for elaboration on the BFS approach suggested in comments. [at]Heuster's answer is better than mine, IMO.

Comment: @amit Heuster's points helps us to decide, to move further or not.

Comment: @amit The main processing part is your algorithm. I think some mathematics is needed to prune our BFS tree. Can you help me to find that.

Comment: @devnull I believe it can be utilized to find the actual path efficiently. I am not sure however if the solution his solution finds is optimal (shortest) or not.

Comment: @amit Lets just forget about the optimized operation sequence part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50078/discussion-between-amit-and-devnull)

Comment: It's your use of `push` and `pop` on a queue that confused me. `enqueue` and `dequeue` (as in the wikipedia article) is much clearer. I suggest you modify your answer to clarify that it's not a stack (implied by `push` and `pop`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you have both `(x,y) always <= target & >0` if not you can always bring them in the range by simple operations. If you consider this constraints you can make a graph where there are `O(target*target)` nodes and edge you can find by doing an operation among three on that node. You now need to evaluate the shortest path from start position node to target node which is `(target,any)`. The assumption here is `(x,y)` values always stay within `(0,target)`. The time complexity is `O(target*target*log(target))` using djikstra.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Vincent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503261/recursion-puzzle/22505727#22505727), I think the proof is not complete.

Let us suppose two relatively prime numbers suppose **n1=19** and **n2=13** whose **GCD** will be **1**. According to him, sequence exits if **k** is multiple of **GCD**.Since every number is multiple of **1**. I think it is not possible for every **k**.